# Permission Set to Restrict Access to Managed Package Specific Custom Metadata

Tags: permission-sets, custom-metadata

We have a managed packaged that ships with a Custom Metadata property and an "Editor" that allows users to modify the Custom Metadata fields and create new ones.

We would like to include a permission set that restricts the modify functionality (Create/Update, we can't do delete from Apex Custom Metadata Deploy) and allows users to still "Read" the metadata.

Under Permission Sets, I see the the "System Permission": `Modify Metadata (Beta if enabled without Modify All Data)` which states:

> Create, edit, and delete org metadata. Users must have appropriate
>   access rights to the metadata they're trying to modify. Some metadata
>   currently requires the Modify All Data permission, so some update
>   attempts can fail if a user doesn't also have the Modify All Data
>   permission

However, this seems to be a "general" grant (as in the user can modify any metadata record they want) so long as they have "Modify All Data" depending on the type?

Under `Permission Set > Object`, only the default tab-view for a Custom Metadata record can be given permissions.

Should we just create a clone VF page with restricted access for the modify operations? Is there another way around this?

`Custom permissions` seems to be specifically for Connected Apps access and do not execute any "Custom" code correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Custom Permissions` pretty much *however you please*. If that means you want to open up part of your UI for users with a certain permission, that is absolutely a valid use case. I have used them dozens of times and never once was it related to Connected Apps.

One piece of advice: across the entire ecosystem, permissions are additive, never restrictive. I highly recommend you have your `Custom Permission` tell you `CanEditMyCustomMetadata` as a whitelist, rather than `CannotEditMyCustomMetadata` as a blacklist.